# creating light box kind of code for a simple task... unable to get the image height even it loads before the height calculation code

Tags: jquery

I am creating a light box kind of code for a simple task.

my problem is when I try to get height even after images loads it shows value 'null'.

trying in console:

```
console.log($('#image-wrap img').height());
```

here is my complete code:

```
$(function(){              
    $.fn.showBig = function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var getURL = $(this).data('url');
            $('<div id="darkbg"/>').css({'opacity':'0.5'}).appendTo('body');
            $('<div id="popup"/>').css({'opacity':'0'}).appendTo('body');
            $('<div id="imageWrap"><img src =' + getURL +'></div>').appendTo('#popup');
            $('<span id="close"/>').text('X').appendTo('#popup');

            var maxHeight = $(window).height(),
                countHeight = $('#image-wrap img').height(),
                countWidth = $('#image-wrap img').width(),
                countTop = $('#image-wrap img').height()/2,
                countLeft = $('#image-wrap img').width()/2;

                console.log($('#image-wrap img').height());

            $('#image-wrap').css({'height':countHeight+'px', 'width':countWidth+'px'});
            $('#popup').css({'margin-left':'-'+countLeft+'px', 'margin-top':'-'+countTop+'px'}).animate({'opacity':'1', 'height':countHeight+'px', 'width':countWidth+'px'})

            $('#popup').closeBig();
        });

    }

    $.fn.closeBig = function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            $('#darkbg, #popup, #close').fadeOut(removeall);

            function removeall(){
                    $(this).remove()
                }

        });
    }

    $('#gallery-list li a').showBig();


});
```

jsfiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/mufeedahmad/R2uwq/1/

thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#imageWrap img').height()` Seems like your previous selector was wrong

Comment: @wolf... my bad.... I have wasted my hour in it... damnnn...

thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('<div id="imageWrap"><img src =' + getURL +'></div>').appendTo('#popup');
```

need to update the ID